# How to install gevent plugin for uwsgi in a virtual environment in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ssl, uwsgi, gevent

I am running **uWSGI (2.0.16)** in ubuntu **16.04**.

When I am running uWSGI from root then it's working fine. But, when I get to run uWSGI in a virtual environment, below error occurs:-

```
uwsgi: unrecognized option '--gevent'
getopt_long() error
```

Then I check the plugin lists of uWSGI in my virtual environment and found gevent plugin is missing.

As per the uWSGI documentation for **uWSGI >= 1.4**

> The gevent plugin is compiled in by default when the default profile
>   is used. Doing the following will install the python plugin as well as
>   the gevent one:
>
> pip install uwsgi

But installing uwsgi by `pip install uwsgi`, still I can't get the gevent plugin in the virtual environment. But, in the similar way when I install uwsgi outside the virtual environment gevent plugin has been available.

I have already tried installing  **uwsgi-plugin-gevent-python**

I had to build uwsgi with **SSL** support so I have used `CFLAGS` for building uWSGI. That ssl support is not working in my virtual environment as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question ranks pretty high for many variations of "uwsgi build plugin gevent support" I figured it could use an answer.

You can verify `uwsgi` isn't loading the `gevent` plugin by running:

```
$ uwsgi --plugins-list
```

If `gevent` isn't listed in the `*** uWSGI loaded generic plugins ***` section then you can compile it, here is how you could do that for python 3.4 (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 here):

```
$ PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4 uwsgi --build-plugin "$UWSGI_DIR/plugins/gevent gevent34"
```

Where `UWSGI_DIR` is the directory path to your uwsgi installation.

If you get an error like:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
```

You are probably missing the `python3-dev` tools, in Ubuntu, you could install those using:

```
$ apt-get install python3-dev
```

And then re-run the build plugin command.

If you don't get an error, you should now have a plugin named `gevent34_plugin.so` in your `UWSGI_DIR`. You can now load that on startup:

```
$ uwsgi --plugins-dir $UWSGI_DIR --plugin gevent34 --plugins-list
```

and `gevent` should be listed somewhere in the `*** uWSGI loaded generic plugins ***` section.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install gevent in the virtualenv? Did you specify the number of async cores to spawn?

I have it running with the following code:

```
pip install uwsgi gevent
uwsgi --gevent 10
```

Of course you should add the configuration to specify the app to run and where should the uswgi application listen for connections.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, I installed gevent and uwsgi_gevetn plugin for the virtual environment. And specifying --gevent 100 in uwsgi as well